# Open Source Cloud Solution( PaaS) to run on my Centos 6 Server

Tags: saas, paas, iaas

I am working on an academic project and my aim is to install an Open Source Cloud (Paas) solution on my Centos 6 Server. Through which I will install open source application for academic purposes and more.

I am new to running a Linux Server command line. I will install my Cloud solution of Choice on a VirtualBox VM.

As of now I am narrowing down to DEIS, CLOUD FOUNDRY, FLYNN and OPEN SHIFT.

My Question is What Cloud Solution is Best for such implentation and what advice you have for a newbie with regards to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that same problem a few years ago. I ended up using [Apache CloudStack](https://cloudstack.apache.org/) because it was "open source". It's not the perfect solution but it gets the job done.
I have also used [vBoxxCloud](https://vboxxcloud.com/) for a while. It's a SaaS tool so I don't know if you can use it. But it has a decent synctool which helps a lot.